# SQL count % statement with a case subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, case

I am trying to create a SQL query that will combine Count with Case. My existing table and query is as follows:

```
Table
Surv_Permit ONLINEoff
0           ONLINE
0           OFFLINE 
1           ONLINE
2           ONLINE
0           OFFLINE 

Query
SELECT
Surv_Permit AS SPStatus,
(COUNT(Surv_Permit)* 100 / (Select Count(Surv_Permit) From dbo.Features)) AS SPPct
FROM dbo.Features
WHERE (ONLINEoff ='ONLINE')
GROUP BY (Surv_Permit)
```

Which gives me this:

```
SPStatus  SPPct
0         10
1         83
2         7
```

What I need is to create a Case subquery for the above query to display 0,1, 2 as No, Yes, and In Progress like this:

```
SPStatus      SPPct
No            10
Yes           83
In Progress   7
```

Thanks, Robert

Comment: that's more a client-side responsibility-  formatting data for human consumption. but the obvious way would be to have a seaprate table that has `0->No`, `1->Yes`, etc.. mappings and just `JOIN` it into your main query.

Answer (score 0):

```
(CASE Surv_Permit 
     WHEN 0 THEN 'No' 
     WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes' 
     ELSE 'In Progress' END) as SPStatus
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE Surv_Permit  
WHEN 0 THEN 'NO' 
WHEN 1 THEN 'YES'
ELSE 'In Progress' END AS SPStatus
,(COUNT(Surv_Permit)* 100 / (Select Count(Surv_Permit) From dbo.Features)) AS SPPct
FROM dbo.Features
WHERE (ONLINEoff ='ONLINE')
GROUP BY (Surv_Permit)
```